# Setting up DBD::SQLite to support a custom version of sqlite3

Tags: perl, sqlite, dbi, dbd

I get a `too many SQL variables` error using a package-default version of `sqlite3`, when I pass in more than 998 variables into a SQL query.

The `sqlite3` binary packaged with `yum` for my OS and version was compiled with support for default variable names (indeed, 999 of them).

I have compiled a version of `sqlite3` from source, using a modified header to bump this default up to a value that is more realistic (e.g., 99999).

In order to integrate this custom version of `sqlite3` with Perl and its DBI interface to the DBD::SQLite plugin — to be able to use this new limit — what modifications do I make to the Perl DBD::SQLite plugin, such that it will use this modified version of `sqlite3` and not the packaged binary (or its libraries) that it currently seems to use?

Comment: You want to pass *a hundred thousand* parameters to your SQL query? Maybe I'm just short of imagination, but I can't think of a situation where that could be a requirement; can you please explain what you're doing? I would also choose something more heavyweight than SQLite to handle such a query.

Comment: `DBD::SQLite` doesn't use `sqlite3`, which is a command-line tool. I think you'll find that the module comes with a prebuilt library. What do you mean by *"using a modified header"* in this context?

Comment: Modified header means a header containing constants, which gets modified to adjust the limits up to some value I'll never need to worry about hitting. Thanks for your help, it pointed me to modify the same constant in the DBD::SQLite plugin source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please examine the documentation for
[`DBD::SQLite`](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/DBD-SQLite-1.56/lib/DBD/SQLite.pm)
under the heading
[*SQLITE VERSION*](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/DBD-SQLite-1.56/lib/DBD/SQLite.pm#SQLITE_VERSION)

It has this about the SQLite library that it uses

> `DBD::SQLite` is usually compiled with a bundled SQLite library (SQLite version 3.22.0 as of this release) for consistency. However, a different version of SQLite may sometimes be used for some reasons like security, or some new experimental features.

See also `DBD::SQLite::compile_options()` in the same document.